# Не появляются элементы в HTML таблице render Django

Tags: html, django

Имеется массив вида:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Не получается занести значения в таблицу

```html
{% for i in dict %}
  <tr>
    {% for j in i %}
      <td>{{ j }}</td>
      <td>{{ j }}</td>
      <td>{{ j }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Вы проверяли, что приходит в переменной dict? Почему Вы по три ячейки сразу выводите?

Comment: Вы назвали свой массив словом dict, что ли?